# grafana: count pods by namespace and namespaces' label

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I'd like to ask how to count all pods in namespaces by namespaces' label value.

The structure is:

- namespace has 'teamName' label to specify a team the ns belongs to
- pod has 'teamName' label to specify a team within the team the pod belongs to

I'd like to count all pods over all namespaces which are belongs to ns.teamName.

I do have selection box (multi) for the ns.teamName `label_values(kube_namespace_labels, teamName)` - stored in `nsTeamName`.

I'm able to chose nsTeamName and for each namespace view the number of the pods `count by (namespace) (kube_pod_info * on (namespace) group_left() kube_namespace_labels{teamName=~"$nsTeamName"})`.

But what I'm not able to figure out how to count all pods in all namespaces with selected `nsTeamName`.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: `count by (teamName) (kube_pod_labels * on(namespace) group_left(teamName) kube_namespace_labels{teamName=~"$nsTeamName"})`.

The `group_left(teamName)` copies the label's value from namespace to pod label. After that counting over `teamName` works correctly.

If there's a better solution, please add it. Thanks